# Key Value For Loop Template - Django Inquiry

Tags: python, django, loops, for-loop, django-templates

Having trouble using Key Value For Loops in the Django Template system and was wondering if anyone could help. I am only able to get results if I include at the end of the for loop "values.1.items" instead of "values.items" which produces nothing.

There are many "values" and I can't for the life of me figure out why I have to specify each item numerically. I want to display all the items through this loop. Thanks for the help!

```
{% for key, values in obj_as_json.items %}
    {% for k, v in values.1.items %}
        {{ k }}: {{ v }}<br><br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

values is a list of of dictionaries rather than a dictionary or a simple list
it would look something like this

```
values = [{'k':'v'},{'k1':'v1'},...]
```

you can loop over it like a list

```
{% for key, values in obj_as_json.items %}
    {% for mydict in values %}
        {%for k,v in mydict.items %}
             ....
```

alternatively you could access it by its index in the list

```
 {% for k,v in values.1.items %}
```

is basically the same as

```
  for k,v in values[1].items():
```

in normal python

Comment: Thank you. I am positive your response is the answer. But I am encountering another problem where two of the values are "int" and therefore throwing the "'int' object is not iterable" error. Any suggestions on how to address that?

Comment: you could write a filter to determine an objects type... or check if the key is in a list of keys that dont return a dictionary

Comment: Thank you - got a basic if statement going in my template. Not pretty, but it works! Much gratitude.